# Внедрение файла в проксируемый сайт

Tags: nginx

Возможно ли внедрить в проксируемый через NGINX сайт например js файл? Хочу уйти от расширения Chrome, т.к. при каждом запуске Chrome оповещает об отключении расширения.

Comment: А сайт, в который вы собрались внедрить, например, js  файл, ваш?

Comment: Нет, иначе бы не было проблем :-)

Comment: Ну и как вы будете внедрять на чужой сайт js? Неужели у этого сайта так плохо с безопасностью, что любой юзер может туда что-то внедрить, выполнить XSS, RCE, SSTI? Не думаю)

Comment: Сайт разработанный украинскими разработчиками, так что какая там безопасность. Расширение ж работает.
Просто Cloud Flare как-то ж внедряет свои rocket-скрипты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот модуль

```
location / {
    sub_filter </head>
        '</head><script language="javascript" src="$script"></script>';
    sub_filter_once on;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Изначально суть комментария была о министерских сервисах, но после правки комментария получилось, что речь об украинских программистах :)